# Coco2d 2.1 and Xcode 7 iOS 9 crash ccShader

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I tested Xcode 7 with but my cocos2d 2.1 games crash on simulator or on devices:

ccShader_PositionColorLenghtTexture_frag.h

```
2015-06-15 22:36:13.319 NanoWar[18789:456971] cocos2d: ERROR: 0:12: '' : syntax error: #extension must always be before any non-preprocessor tokens
```

and

```
cocos2d: ERROR: 0:26: Invalid call of undeclared identifier 'fwidth'
```

This class crash the game

```
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable                                                                             

#ifdef GL_ES                                                                                                                
varying mediump vec4 v_color;                                                                                               
varying mediump vec2 v_texcoord;                                                                                            
#else                                                                                                                       
varying vec4 v_color;                                                                                                       
varying vec2 v_texcoord;                                                                                                    
#endif                                                                                                                      

void main()                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                           
#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives                                                                                          
#if defined GL_OES_standard_derivatives                                                                                     
    gl_FragColor = v_color*smoothstep(0.0, length(fwidth(v_texcoord)), 1.0 - length(v_texcoord));                           
#else                                                                                                                       
    gl_FragColor = v_color*step(0.0, 1.0 - length(v_texcoord));                                                             
#endif                                                                                                                      
#endif                                                                                                                      
}
```

Comment: Discussion here (see rae's answer): http://forum.cocos2d-objc.org/t/xcode-7-ios9-beta/17346/6

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm "rae" on [forum.cocos2d-objc.org](http://forum.cocos2d-objc.org) and I might as well put my answer here as well, since all roads lead to StackOverflow. :-)

If you are using an older release of Cocos 2D, this may help. I edited CCGLProgram.m to change the beginning of the -(BOOL)compileShader: method thusly:

```
#define EXTENSION_STRING "#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable"
static NSString * g_extensionStr = @EXTENSION_STRING;

- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type byteArray:(const GLchar *)source
{
    GLint status;

    if (!source)
        return NO;

    // BEGIN workaround for Xcode 7 bug
    BOOL hasExtension = NO;
    NSString *sourceStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:source];
    if([sourceStr rangeOfString:g_extensionStr].location != NSNotFound) {
        hasExtension = YES;
        NSArray *strs = [sourceStr componentsSeparatedByString:g_extensionStr];
        assert(strs.count == 2);
        sourceStr = [strs componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
        source = (GLchar *)[sourceStr UTF8String];
    }

    const GLchar *sources[] = {
        (hasExtension ? EXTENSION_STRING "\n" : ""),
    #ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
        (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "precision highp float;\n" : "precision mediump float;\n"),
    #endif
        "uniform mat4 CC_PMatrix;\n"
        "uniform mat4 CC_MVMatrix;\n"
        "uniform mat4 CC_MVPMatrix;\n"
        "uniform vec4 CC_Time;\n"
        "uniform vec4 CC_SinTime;\n"
        "uniform vec4 CC_CosTime;\n"
        "uniform vec4 CC_Random01;\n"
        "//CC INCLUDES END\n\n",
        source,
    };
    // END workaround for Xcode 7 bug
```

It's a hack, but it works for up to Xcode 7 beta 2. Hope this is helpful to someone googling for this.

Reid

Comment: in case you are also supporting iOS version prior to iOS 8.0 than just make sure to replace [sourceStr containsString:g_extensionStr] with [sourceStr rangeOfString:g_extensionStr].location != NSNotFound since - (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)str NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);

Comment: Thanks Sanjay! I incorporated your change.

Comment: This solution didn't work for cocos2d v2.2, but answer from @bodagetta works well.

Comment: Works with a project built on Xcode3 that I just opened on 9 without hope. Cheers +1 for sure

Comment: Seems to work with Xcode 11 and iOS 13.2. I just got my old cocos2d game to compile again.

Comment: Works for me with Xcode 12.4 in https://www.raywenderlich.com/2736-trigonometry-for-game-programming-part-1-2 and cocos2d-iphone-classic-2.2.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer did not work for me, but this did.

Go to the file named `CCGLProgram.m`

Replace the entire method named `- (BOOL)compileShader:(CLuint *)shader type(GLenum)typebyteArray:(const GLchar *)source`

with this method

```
#define _IPHONE9_0 [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] == 9.000

#define EXTENSION_STRING "#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable"
static NSString * g_extensionStr = @EXTENSION_STRING;


- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type byteArray:(const GLchar *)source
{
GLint status;
if (!source)
    return NO;


#ifdef _IPHONE9_0

NSLog(@"USING IOS9 shaders");
// BEGIN workaround for Xcode 7 ios9----
BOOL hasExtension = NO;
NSString *sourceStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:source];
if([sourceStr containsString:g_extensionStr]) {
    hasExtension = YES;
    NSArray *strs = [sourceStr componentsSeparatedByString:g_extensionStr];
    assert(strs.count == 2);
    sourceStr = [strs componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    source = (GLchar *)[sourceStr UTF8String];
}

const GLchar *sources[] = {
    (hasExtension ? EXTENSION_STRING "\n" : ""),
#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
    (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "precision highp float;\n" : "precision mediump float;\n"),
 #endif
    "uniform mat4 CC_PMatrix;\n"
    "uniform mat4 CC_MVMatrix;\n"
    "uniform mat4 CC_MVPMatrix;\n"
    "uniform vec4 CC_Time;\n"
    "uniform vec4 CC_SinTime;\n"
    "uniform vec4 CC_CosTime;\n"
    "uniform vec4 CC_Random01;\n"
    "//CC INCLUDES END\n\n",
    source,
};
#else

NSLog(@"USING IOS8 shaders");

const GLchar *sources[] = {
#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
    (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "precision highp float;\n" : "precision mediump float;\n"),
#endif
    "uniform mat4 CC_PMatrix;\n"
    "uniform mat4 CC_MVMatrix;\n"
    "uniform mat4 CC_MVPMatrix;\n"
    "uniform vec4 CC_Time;\n"
    "uniform vec4 CC_SinTime;\n"
    "uniform vec4 CC_CosTime;\n"
    "uniform vec4 CC_Random01;\n"
    "//CC INCLUDES END\n\n",
    source,
};

#endif


*shader = glCreateShader(type);
glShaderSource(*shader, sizeof(sources)/sizeof(*sources), sources, NULL);
glCompileShader(*shader);

glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);

if( ! status ) {
    GLsizei length;
    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_SHADER_SOURCE_LENGTH, &length);
    GLchar src[length];

    glGetShaderSource(*shader, length, NULL, src);
    CCLOG(@"cocos2d: ERROR: Failed to compile shader:\n%s", src);

    if( type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER )
        CCLOG(@"cocos2d: %@", [self vertexShaderLog] );
    else
        CCLOG(@"cocos2d: %@", [self fragmentShaderLog] );

    abort();
}
return ( status == GL_TRUE );
}
```

Comment: I'm using cocos2d-iphone 2.1 I think it's different for you if you using a recent version of cocos2d.

Comment: Used this for Cocos2d version 2.1 and it worked like a charm :D! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Using the accepted answer above, but for newer versions of cocos2d:

In CCShader.m replace the lines

```
static GLint
CompileShaderSources(GLenum type, NSArray *sources)
{
```

with

```
#define EXTENSION_STRING "#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable"
static NSString * g_extensionStr = @EXTENSION_STRING;

static NSArray * PrependExtensionIfNeeded(NSArray *sources)
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableSources = [NSMutableArray array];

    BOOL hasExtension = NO;

    for (NSString *source in sources)
    {
        NSString *newSource = [source copy];
        if([source rangeOfString:g_extensionStr].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            hasExtension = YES;
            NSArray *strs = [source componentsSeparatedByString:g_extensionStr];
            newSource = [strs componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
        }

        [mutableSources addObject:newSource];
    }

    if (hasExtension)
    {
        NSMutableString *firstSource = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[mutableSources firstObject]];
        [firstSource insertString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", g_extensionStr] atIndex:0];
        [mutableSources replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:firstSource];
    }

    return mutableSources;
}

static GLint
CompileShaderSources(GLenum type, NSArray *sources)
{
    sources = PrependExtensionIfNeeded(sources);
```

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: Wanted to write this as a comment but don't have enough reputation to write a comment, hence writing this as an answer:

The fix described by [Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31173759/2326639) does fix the issue.  However it crashes on iOS 7 devices, because it uses `containsString` method which is only available in iOS 8 and above

A simple change to the following line fixes the issue:

```c
if([sourceStr containsString:g_extensionStr]) {
```

needs to be changed to:

```c
NSRange range = [sourceStr rangeOfString:g_extensionStr];
if(range.length > 0) {
```