# Crackling noise on playback on iOS9 and 9.1 (libPD + cocos2d + xcode 7.1)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, libpd

I'm writing an app using cocos2d and libpd on iOS. After updating XCode to 7.1 I had to do a workaround regarding CG shaders not setting up correctly, as per: [Coco2d 2.1 and Xcode 7 iOS 9 crash ccShader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864055/coco2d-2-1-and-xcode-7-ios-9-crash-ccshader)

Unfortunately I started getting crackling noise on playback on iOS9 and 9.1 devices. Pre iOS 9 don't display this problem. I'm wondering whether it has something to do with the shaders workaround.

anybody with the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that crackling has nothing to do with iOS9 or XCode 7. The object initialising libpd has been initialised twice causing the audio engine to have two active copies.