# First working version of cocos2d v2.0 for iOS 12?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm looking to update an old app of mine that users a version of cocos2D (obj-c) back in 2013/14. Though booting up the project after all this time has rendered it full of errors.

I've tried replacing the old coco2D folder with the latest from cocos2D-x (ios) but that hasn't worked and let to further errors.

Just wondering if anyone has tried to update their old cocos2D and found a version where it began to support 64bit as I believe that's around the time Apple began to phase out my apps and i didn't update them.

Comment: Yes, I used old Cocos2d 2.0 code and updated it to Cocos2d 2.2 and done some minor tweaks...see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531267/cocos2d-iphone-and-iphone-x-resolution/52725972#52725972

Comment: Thanks mate. This’ll be my last attempt to bring back my games.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Marin hey mate, yes I did. Though they’re barely running and need a lot more work. What I did was update it to cocos2d 2.2 which you can find on github. You want to remove the old folder and add the folder downloaded from github. You’ll then come across a plethora of errors, that’s the hard part and it should work after that assuming you have third party libraries or old Apple libraries you’ll have those too

Comment: Thank you @Mark , I just downloaded 2.2.6 I'm assuming that'll work? Thanks for replying after 2 months!

Comment: @Marin No worries, I can’t confirm that 2.2.6 works as i don’t remember the version number. I’m pretty sure that was the gist of it though.That was off the top of my head, as I remember trying to get the core cocos2d framework going and nothing else. I’ve resurrected two apps so far, and one uses box2d. Oh yeah if you’re using box2d you will have to delete the original folder with whatever is packaged on the github version. Another note is that you will have to do some refactoring with the opengles files, renaming and sorting out types

Comment: @Mark Yes indeed I am using Box2d thank you for bringing it up! Your input is very valuable i'm sure it will help others who want to resurrect old games.

Comment: @Marin Here you go mate. https://github.com/markhmwong/MachX. Maybe you can cross reference the code to help you through it. Just a fair warning, there are horrible coding practices within that game.

Comment: @Mark that's very nice of you! I can just try and run it i assume no issue with provisioning ? I will have to cross reference the Box2D and Cocos2d as I'm getting lots of errors in the Box2D especially ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments. Please review my comment I made with Marin.

github.com/markhmwong/MachX - a working and playable project that I've tested on an iPhone X

Comment: Hi,...Do you have any sample using cocos2d 2.2 which uses shader program and working in iOS 12 ? Now my shaders code not working with your MachX cocos2d lib...help me to fix.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55104186/shader-program-not-working-in-cocos2d-2-2-obj-c-ios-12

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor unfortunately not. This is the best I could do so far.